# Rebol parse: dealing with whitespace and copy var

Tags: rebol

I read chapter 15:
http://www.rebol.com/docs/core23/rebolcore-15.html#section-8"

```
spacer: charset reduce [tab newline #" "]
spaces: [some spacer]
rule: ["a" spaces "b" spaces "c"]
parse/all "a b c" rule
```

is OK but if I change rule to just

```
rule: ["a" spaces copy varb to spaces "c"]
parse/all "a b c" rule
```

Rebol Console outputs error:

```
** Script Error: Invalid argument: some spacer
** Where: halt-view
** Near: parse/all "a b c" rule
>>
```

Why ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In REBOL 2 the argument of the TO operation of PARSE can't be a complex rule - it must be a literal value or character set. The code `[to spaces]` is equivalent to `[to [some spacer]]` and that just won't work. In your example you can convert `[to spaces]` to `[to spacer spaces]` and it should work just fine.

There are tricks to get around this, that mostly involve refactoring the `[to [some spacer]]` to be `[any non-spacer]` where non-spacer is the complement of the spacer character set.

It is intended that this will be fixed in REBOL 3, but that fix hasn't been done yet, and complementing a character set doesn't work as well because of Unicode. Stick with REBOL 2 for now.